# How to chain filter expressions together

Tags: kotlin

I have data in the following format

```
ArrayList<Map.Entry<String,ByteString>>
[
  {"a":[a-bytestring]},
  {"b":[b-bytestring]},
  {"a:model":[amodel-bytestring]},
  {"b:model":[bmodel-bytestring]},
]
```

I am looking for a *clean* way to transform this data into the format (`List<Map.Entry<ByteString,ByteString>>`) where the `key` is the value of `a` and `value` is the value of `a:model`.

Desired output

```
List<Map.Entry<ByteString,ByteString>>
[
  {[a-bytestring]:[amodel-bytestring]},
  {[b-bytestring]:[bmodel-bytestring]}
]
```

I assume this will involve the use of filters or other map operations but am not familiar enough with Kotlin yet to know this

Comment: Hmm, this data doesn't look like a list of maps, but just a map. Also, why values seem to differ in types? Do we have any guarantees on the data? For example is it guaranteed that `a:model` has its corresponding `a`?

Comment: Apologies, just fixed a couple errors. The data is a list of map entries and the data is guaranteed to be in this format. Each a will have an a:model

Comment: What is `ByteString` here?  (Also, there's still a type conflict in your desired output.)

Comment: Fixed, thank you. ByteString is an encrypted string in this case.

Comment: Type conflict = `ArrayList<Map<ByteString,ByteString>>` in your paragraph text vs `List<Map.Entry<ByteString,ByteString>>` in your "desired output". Not bothered about ArrayList vs List, but more about Map vs Map.Entry.

Comment: Fixed. Sorry for the confusion @k314159

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible to give an exact, tested answer without access to the `ByteString` class — but I don't think that's needed for an outline, as we don't need to manipulate byte strings, just pass them around. So here I'm going to substitute `Int`; it should be clear and avoid any dependencies, but still work in the same way.

I'm also going to use a more obvious input structure, which is simply a map:

```
val input = mapOf("a" to 1,
                  "b" to 2,
                  "a:model" to 11,
                  "b:model" to 12)
```

As I understand it, what we want is to link each key *without* `:model` with the corresponding one *with* `:model`, and return a map of their corresponding values.

That can be done like this:

```
val output = input.filterKeys{ !it.endsWith(":model") }
                  .map{ it.value to input["${it.key}:model"] }.toMap()

println(output) // Prints {1=11, 2=12}
```

The first line filters out all the entries whose keys end with `:model`, leaving only those without. Then the second creates a map from their values to the input values for the corresponding `:model` keys. (Unfortunately, there's no good general way to create one map *directly* from another; here `map()` creates a list of pairs, and then `toMap()` creates a map from that.)

I think if you replace `Int` with `ByteString` (or indeed any other type!), it should do what you ask.

The only thing to be aware of is that the output is a `Map<Int, Int?>` — i.e. the values are nullable. That's because there's no guarantee that each input key has a corresponding `:model` key; if it doesn't, the result will have a null value. If you want to omit those, you could call `filterValues{ it != null }` on the result.

However, if there's an ‘orphan’ `:model` key in the input, it will be ignored.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Thank you for the thorough explanation, definitely helped me understand the best way chain these operators together